# Android webview has different rendering engine than Chrome -- How do I find the browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

I am using `android.webkit.WebView` on an Android 4.3 (Nexus 7). Some pages look completely different in the web view vs Chrome browser on tablet.

What browser engine is it actually using so I can have people test without having to install the application. Is there some sort of default Android browser besides Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

For pre-4.4 versions of Android :
Specific makers (like Samsung and LG) sell phones that contain a WebKit based browser which is used in WebViews. Other makers like Motorola, Google and HTC include Chrome in their version of Android and that's what the WebView to render web content. when using Samsung devices - I encountered significant differences in rendering between Chrome and the builtin WebKit based browser.

For Android KitKat (4.4) and after - the WebView uses a Chrome based rendering engine to render web content so the web pages you display in Chrome and in your app should display the same or at least look similar.

Hope this helps,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

No, not as far as i know,  the WebView has it's own proprietary rendering engine, as of 4.4 (KitKat) it is based on the chrome rendering engine however.

Answer (score 0):

`WebView` is using two different clients, they are `WebViewClient` and `WebChromeClient`. Each of it has different functionality (see more in Android developer docs), and as far as I know users doesn't have to install the app (Chrome, or etc) as both clients are already embedded in Android OS.